# R : error while retrieving from shiny's sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

i am a student at coursera data science specialization, and sometimes i'd like to recreate the example that the instructor shows to get my hands used on R coding and so on,
right now i am creating that shiny app and used shiny's sliderinput with 2 values but the plot always says "Error: invalid arguments"
i spotted the error in the sliders as i changed them with fixed values  it works fine, so here's the  code and hope u guild me if i did anything wrong.

That's the ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot Random Number"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(
        "numeric",
        "How Many Random Numbers Should be Plotted",
        value = 1000,
        min = 1,
        max = 1000,
        step = 1
      ),
      sliderInput(
        "sliderX",
        "Pick minimum and maximum X values",
        min = -100,
        max = 100,
        value = c(-50, 50)
      ),
      sliderInput(
        "SliderY",
        "Pick minimum and maximum Y values",
        min = -100,
        max = 100,
        value = c(-50, 50)
      ),
      checkboxInput("show_xlab", "Show/Hide X Axis Label", value = TRUE),
      checkboxInput("show_ylab", "Show/Hide Y Axis Label", value = TRUE),
      checkboxInput("show_title", "Show/Hide plot title", value = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(h3("Graph of Random Points"),
              plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
))
```

and that's the server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(12345)
    num.of.points <- input$numeric
    minX <- input$sliderX[1] #i know the error here
    maxX <- input$sliderX[2] #but i guess that's the right way though
    minY <- input$SliderY[1] #so is anything has changed !
    maxY <- input$sliderY[2]
    dataX <- runif(num.of.points, minX, maxX)
    dataY <- runif(num.of.points, minY, maxY)
    labx <- ifelse(input$show_xlab, "X Axis", "")
    laby <- ifelse(input$show_ylab, "Y Axis", "")
    main.title <- ifelse(input$show_title, "Title", "")
    qplot(
      x = dataX,
      y = dataY,
      xlab = labx,
      ylab = laby,
      main = main.title,
      xlim = c(-100, 100),
      ylim  = c(-100, 100)
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped a variable name here:

> ```
> minX <- input$sliderX[1]
> maxX <- input$sliderX[2]
> minY <- input$SliderY[1]
> maxY <- input$sliderY[2]
> ```

The variable names are case-sensitive.
In the inputs, you have defined `sliderX` and `SliderY`.
I suggest to rename the input to `sliderY`, and change `minY` to this:

```
minY <- input$sliderY[1]
```

Comment: WoW, i wonder how can u even notice that, but thanks a lot i would give u voting up but unfortunately i am still  beginner, But thanks a lot for your help mate